# How to show all products on the first page by using struts?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I wanna know how to show all products data on the first jsp page.
I retrieved products data from the database and returned **List array.** And then, I don't know how to show this array in jsp.

I want to call *http://localhost:8080/StrutsPrj/jsp/showAllProduct.jsp* that page will show on all of the products. But I don't know how to configure that first page at the struts-config.xml and how to call related action of this page.

Please check the following code:

**ShowAllProductAction :::::::**

```
Database db = new Database();
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
    ProductForm myForm = (ProductForm)form;
    List<ProductForm> prodList = db.getProduct();
    myForm.setProdList(prodList);
    return mapping.findForward("success");
}
```

**struts-config.xml ::::::**

```
<form-beans>
     <form-bean name="ProdForm" type="action.ProductForm"/>
</form-beans>

<action-mappings>
  <action name="ProdForm" path="/showProduct" type="action.ShowAllProduct" scope="request" >
    <forward name="success" path="/jsp/showProduct.jsp"/>
  </action>
</action-mappings>
```

path="/showProduct" is not had in any jsp but I added this path because  tag must has path. :D

**showAllProduct.jsp ::::::**

```
<logic:notEmpty name="userBean" property="searchControl">
   <c:forEach var="i" begin="${userBean.begin}" end="${userBean.end}" step="1">
    ${userBean.prodList[i-1].productName}<br/>
    ${userBean.prodList[i-1].modelNo}<br/>
    ${userBean.prodList[i-1].brief}<br/>
    ${userBean.prodList[i-1].price}<br/><hr/>
   </c:forEach>
</logic:notEmpty>
```

I've an error : **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The path of an ForwardConfig cannot be null**

What's wrong at this code? 
If you don't mind, please explain me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
Database db = new Database(); 
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {     
     List<ProductForm> prodList = db.getProduct();     
     request.setAttribute("prodList", prodList);
     return mapping.findForward("success"); 
}
```

In jsp

```
<logic:iterate name="prodList" id="product">
<p>
  <bean:write name="product" property="productName"/>
  <bean:write name="product" property ="modelNo"/>
  etc ...
</p>
</logic:iterate>
```

Comment: I changed just like you but I have an error **javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean: "prodList" in any scope** Why this error occur? Please, explain me. Thanks.

Comment: you have not added this line   request.setAttribute("prodList", prodList);  in execute method, before return statement

Comment: I already added request.setAttribute("prodList", prodList); in execute method. But I've this error **javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean: "prodList" in any scope**. I don't know how to solve this problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should call `http://localhost:8080/StrutsPrj/showProduct.do` but not `http://localhost:8080/StrutsPrj/jsp/showAllProduct.jsp`